# Postgresql 16 initial config

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Yesterday I installed postgre, *the only thing I have done in my **GNU/Linux** system was to add the repositories and install!* When I try to follow a tutorial to learn Postgres, **I can not connect to the database neither from pgadmin4**, nor from the terminal. It tells me something like **the password of the user "postgres" is incorrect**, but I am 100% sure that **I have not modified that password**. That means that I can not create any database (*when I opened my pgadmin I did not see any database created, which in the tutorials that I searched all over youtube, there was always a DB created by default)* Is there any way to correct this error?

[postgresql workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atJ0h.png)

I have searched for info in the documentation and youtube videos about the installation and configuration process.

Comment: Hard to help you, since we don't know how you installed PostgreSQL, how you ran initdb, etc. etc. etc. And we don't have access to your computer either. I think something went wrong during one of these steps: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime.html

Comment: It's common for distributions to create a system account called `postgres` that owns the default "database cluster".  I'd suggest running `sudo -u postgres createuser -d $USER` to create a role/account for yourself within Postgres

Comment: Show us the exact error message, not "something like" the error message.

Comment: Different Linux distributions have different initial setups.  What distribution are you using what repository did you install?

Comment: I have uninstalled postgres, thanks but my head was blowing with postgres, now i have installed mariaDB and works everything fine! Thanks for all. (may be a distro problem)